# Execute multiple command through SSH using sudo

Tags: shell-script, sudo, sshpass

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS="," read -r f1 f2
do
 username="testuser"
 SSHPASS='abcde' sshpass -e ssh -t "$username@$f1" "sudo su - root -c 'yum -y install wget'"< /dev/null ;  
done < Input.txt
```

Now i would like to not only get `wget` installed, but execute a script.
eg: Grep and check if services are running, Remove unwanted folders, etc.
I've tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS="," read -r f1 f2
do
  username="testuser"
  SSHPASS='abcde' sshpass -e ssh -t "$username@$f1" "sudo su - root -c
  if [ -d /opt/xxxx ]; then
    rm -rf /opt/xxxx
  if [ -d /etc/xxxx ]; then
    rm -rf /etc/xxxx
  fi"< /dev/null ;
done < Input.txt
```

It seems not to work.
How could I pass a script to execute as root on a remote machine ?

Comment: What is your error message? You missed a "fi;" statement after the line "rm -rf /opt/xxxx" and you should probably write all statements in one line using ';' to separate statements. This worked for me: ssh -t localhost "sudo su - root -c 'if [ -d /opt/xxxx/ ]; then ls /opt/xxxx/; fi; if [ -d /etc/ ]; then echo \"etc exists\"; fi;'"

Comment: i have made changes in the code and added if and fi properly.
Please find the error faced.----------
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known

Comment: Your "could not resolve hostname" error is pretty self explanatory.  What happens when you do `nslookup hostname` or `dig +short hostname`, where "hostname" is your remote host.

Answer (score 2):

Running multiple commands with sudo can be done in multiple ways, see  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-run-multiple-commands-in-sudo-under-linux-or-unix/

For example the followwing will produce two lines of output, the first containing a timestamp of your local machine, the second 'root'.

`sudo -- sh -c 'date; whoami'`

You can give this to ssh in double quotes to execute it on a remote machine. Like the following.

`ssh [options] "sudo -- sh -c 'date; whoami'"`

The [options] should be replaced by whatever options you want to give to ssh, including the remote hostname.